# Sandisk SD-Card freeze after CMD41

Tags: sd-card, spi, ftdi

I'm using FTDI C232HM USB->SPI cable using Windows10

The issue is: once I send CMD41 to SanDisk 4GB microSD card, it replay with "1" then doesn't replay to any other command

the init commands are the

1. Set CS pin HIGH (deselects the slave)
2. Toggle clock 80 times
3. Set CS pin LOW (selects the slave)
4. Send `CMD0`:  `0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x95` (response: `0x01`)
5. Send `CMD8`:  `0x48,0x00,0x00,0x01,0xAA,0x87` (response is `0x01; 0x000001AA`)
6. Send `CMD55`: `0x77,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00` (response: `0x01`)
7. Send `ACMD41`:`0x69,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00` (response: `0x01`)
8. Send `CMD55`: `0x77,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00` (response: `0xFF`) loop forever

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Roy

Added DUMMY `0XFF` before any Send SPI command
Added DUMMY `0XFF + 0xFF` before any Send SPI command

```c
SD_PowerOn();
Sleep(100);
SD_SendCmd(CMD0, 0);

if (SD_SendCmd(CMD0, 0) == 1) 
{ 
    Timer1 = 100;

    if (SD_SendCmd(CMD8, 0x1AA) == 1) 
    { 
        do {
            if (SD_SendCmd(CMD55, 0) <= 1)
            {
                n = SD_SendCmd(CMD41, 1UL << 30);
                if(n == 0)
                    break; /* ACMD41 with HCS bit */
             }
         } while (Timer1--);

         if (Timer1 && SD_SendCmd(CMD58, 0) == 0) 
         { 
             for (n = 0; n < 4; n++)
             {
                 ocr[n] = SPI_RxByte();
             }
             type = (ocr[0] & 0x40) ? 6 : 2;
         }
    }
```